# apache ftpclient retrievefile() downloading corrupted file

Tags: java, apache, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient for downloading files from ftp server.

It downloads all the files from my ftp server except those files with names like test.xml test.txt west.xml etc., The files with these names are getting downloaded with no data inside the file. retrieveFile() method is returning boolean false for these files.

I tried to download the same file by renaming its name manually on ftp server. It worked well with other names.

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

EDIT- Adding sample code

```
public static boolean downloadFTPDir(String localDir, FTPClient ftpClient) {
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {

        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        /*
         * Use passive mode as default because most of us are behind
         * firewalls these days.
         */
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        FTPFile[] fileList = ftpClient.listFiles();

        for (FTPFile ftpFile : fileList) {
            if(ftpFile.isDirectory()){
                String tempDir = localDir + File.separatorChar+ftpFile.getName();
                try {
                    File temp = new File(tempDir);
                    temp.mkdirs();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Could not create local directory "+tempDir);
                    return false;
                }
                if(ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpFile.getName())) {
                    downloadFTPDir(tempDir, ftpClient);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Could change directory to "+ftpFile.getName()+" on FTP server");
                    return false;
                }

            } else {
                output = new FileOutputStream(localDir + File.separatorChar + ftpFile.getName());
                if (!ftpClient.retrieveFile(ftpFile.getName(), output)) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to download file from FTP server : " + ftpFile.getName());
                    File tmp = null;
                    try {
                        output.close();
                        /*tmp = new File(localDir + File.separatorChar + ftpFile.getName());
                        tmp.delete();
                        logger.info("Deleted corrupt downloaded file : " + tmp.getAbsolutePath());*/
                    } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Connection to FTP server  is closed ");
                        return false;
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        System.out.println("Unable to delete corrupt file from local directory : " + tmp.getAbsolutePath());
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                output.close();
                System.out.println("FTP file download successful : " + ftpFile.getName());
            }

        }

    } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e3) {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (Exception e4) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    } finally{
        try {
            if(output!=null)
                output.close();
        } catch (Exception e5) {
            e5.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect("FTP IP", 21);
        System.out.println("connecting");
        if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReply())) {
            System.out.println("connected");
            if(!ftpClient.login("FTP username", "FTP Password")) {
                System.out.println("could not login");
                ftpClient.disconnect();
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("logged in");
            String remotePath = "FTP directory Path";
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(remotePath, "/");
            String dir = null;

            boolean status = false;
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    dir = st.nextToken();
                    status = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(dir);

                    if (!status) {
                        System.out.println("FTP client is not able to change the current directory to " + dir);
                        return ;
                    }

                }
            System.out.println("connected");
            downloadFTPDir("local path", ftpClient);
        } else {
            ftpClient.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code, without that, it is pretty hard to help.

Comment: @ppeterka added the sample code.

Comment: Text files are not usually binary.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ ok. But how about XML files with test.xml as its name?

Comment: Still not binary. Binary files are typically application files. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ Which file type should I use in case of xml? I tried with other file types available, but it did not help me.

Comment: ASCII - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.2/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html